# How to write underbraces numbers in parentheses?

Tags: math-mode, vector

[image]

How to write the above in LaTeX? How to bring the brackets?

Comment: Hi! Is the image the result that you want? I mean, wouldn't you prefer to have the 2,2,2,2... aligned with the equal sign?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYrBw.png) seems for better visually. The large parentheses seem completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! A very simple-minded possibility is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
 \underbrace{2,2,2,2,2,}_{5}\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{995}\\
 ~
\end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say that there are fancier/better-looking options available.

Answer (score 5):

Something less disgraceful than the shown picture:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
{\underbrace{2,2,2,2,2}_{5}},{\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{995}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The “proper” way:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\beta=\bigl(\,{\underbrace{2,2,2,2,2}_{5}},{\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{995}}\,\bigr)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The ugly way:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\beta=\left(
\begin{matrix}
\vphantom{\Big|}
{\underbrace{2,2,2,2,2,}_{\vphantom{\bigg|}\textstyle 5}}\,
{\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{\vphantom{\bigg|}\textstyle 995}}
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, to have the series of numbers aligned with the equal sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \beta = \left( \underbrace{2,2,2,2,2,}_{5}\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{995} \right)
    \]
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]